# python program gave two different output

Tags: python

Why two different outputs from these programs?

## First program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
sum = 0
for i in range(1,11): 
    sum = sum + i 
print("Sum of first 10 natural number :", sum )

Sum of first 10 natural number : 55
```

## Second program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 11):
    sum = sum + i
    print(sum)


1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55
```

Comment: Identation plays a very important role in Python code. Read through its documentation which will help you understand why your output is different.

Comment: indentation i believe. first program indentation is on start. and second program is same align with variable sum. so it might print every operation rather than first program print after operation is finish

Answer (score 1):

Due to different indentation you get different results:

### Code 1:

```py
sum = 0
for i in range(1,11): 
    sum = sum + i 
print("Sum of first 10 natural number :", sum )   # <--- considered outside for loop
```

### Output:

```
Sum of first 10 natural number : 55
```

### Code 2:

```py
sum = 0
for i in range(1,11): 
    sum = sum + i 
    print(sum)    # <--- considered inside for loop
```

### Output:

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, your `print` statement is *inside* the loop so it runs after every single accumulation.

In the first case, being outside the loop means it executes only when the loop is done.

In Python, indentation is *very* important.